# Retrieve an XML value using xpath with attributes containing hyphens and string

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to read a seven day forecast that has up to seven elements called `<forecast-period>`. Each `<forecast-period>` has three elements called `<text>` with a `type` attribute and I want to retrieve the `<text>` element that contains a sentence. The XML file is available at ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10705.xml

The basic XPath ends up being ....

```
product/forecast/area[1]/forecast-period[@start-time-local="2018-04-24"]/text[@type="forecast"]
```

I would like to have a PHP function that parses a date and returns the text content of this element, however I am struggling with parsing the variable `$strDate` and the hyphens in the attributes.

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents('ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10705.xml');
$strDate = '2017-04-30T05:00:00+10:00';
echo getPrecisForDate($xml,$strDate); 

function getPrecisForDate($xml,$strDate) {
  $precis = @$xml->forecast->area[1]->{'forecast-period'}[@start-time-local=$strDate]->text[@type="forecast"];
  return $precis;
}
```

Can you please assist with my syntax to retrieve the text content without using a loop and using a variable as a date.

Comment: Can you post about example xml?

Comment: You're passing a string to your function and then somehow expecting to be able to treat it as some kind of magical object/array/something. That's not going to work well (and it's still not valid PHP code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string to your function and then somehow expecting to be able to treat it as some kind of magical object/array/something. This will not work. First step is to [load the XML into a parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php). Then you'll need to run an [XPath query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) on the document to find the element that you want.

The XPath query you were using would not have worked, as the `start-time-local` attribute is a full date/time string, and you were only looking for a date. I changed it to use the [`starts-with()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303516/how-to-use-the-starts-with-xpath-function) instead.

```php
<?php
$url = "ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10705.xml";
$date = "2017-04-27";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$xpq = "/product/forecast/area[2]/forecast-period[starts-with(@start-time-local, '$date')]/text[@type='forecast']";
$nodes = $xpath->query($xpq);
echo $nodes[0]->textContent;
```

Output:

```
Partly cloudy. Slight (30%) chance of a shower in the late morning and afternoon. Winds south to southwesterly 20 to 25 km/h turning westerly 15 to 20 km/h in the evening.
```

The XML that you linked to had no such text element in `area[1]` so I used `area[2]` instead. If you're looking for a particular area you should do so by checking for `area[@aac='whatever']` instead of relying on position.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I appreciate the time and effort detailing this all and you are correct about the area[2] instead of [1].

Comment: No worries, answers aren't helpful without the details! Do use the `aac` attribute value to grab the element you're after though, you never know when the data format will change.